# When is Fun(X,C) comonadic over C with respect to the colimit functor?

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, infinity-categories

Because I'm primarily interested in this question from the point of view of $\infty$-categories (in this case, modeled by quasicategories), I'll ask this question using that terminology. In particular, I'll just say "category" instead of $\infty$-category or quasicategory, to keep things legible. I suspect that, up to adding in the word "homotopy," a lot of what I'm going to say holds very generally.

It's not hard to work out that if $Top$ is the category of $\infty$-groupoids (or anima, according to Peter Scholze), then there is an equivalence between comodules over any $X\in Top$, with respect to the Cartesian monoidal structure, and the slice category $Top/X$. I'll write $Comod_X(Top)\simeq Top/X$. Furthermore, by Lurie's straightening/unstraightening (a.k.a. the $\infty$-categorical Grothendieck construction), we have an equivalence $Top/X\simeq Fun(X,Top)$. The first category, $Comod_X(Top)$, is clearly comonadic over $Top$ via the forgetful functor $U\colon Comod_X(Top)→Top$. Moreover, the colimit functor $Fun(X,Top)→Top$ factors through $Comod_X(Top)$ and is the left adjoint of an adjoint equivalence realizing the composite equivalence $Comod_X(Top)≃Fun(X,Top)$. Thus, $Fun(X,Top)$ is comonadic over $Top$ via the colimit functor $colim\colon Fun(X,Top)→Top$.

My question is whether or not this is more generally true, perhaps for some generic abstract reasons that I'm not aware or, or not seeing. Note that it is *not* in general true (I don't think) that $colim:Fun(D,C)→C$ is comonadic for arbitrary categories $D$ and $C$. However, I'm happy with assuming that $D$ is an $∞$-groupoid and that $C$ is "nice," i.e. at least (locally) presentable.

So really the question is, are there check-able conditions under which the colimit functor $colim:Fun(X,C)→C$ is comonadic, under the assumptions that $X$ is an $∞$-groupoid and $C$ is presentable?

Comment: The case of spaces is even better than comonadic because the forgetful functor preserves all contractible limits. Maybe one can argue more generally that, when X is a groupoid and C is presentable, this colimit functor will commute with all contractible limits? That seems reasonable to prove by presenting C as a localization of presheaves and reducing to that case. Worth a try...

Comment: Where does Scholze call $\infty$-groupoids anima?

Comment: In fact, doesn’t it seem like the properties of a left adjoint to be (i) conservative and (ii) preserve some collection of limits K, are both preserved under tensoring in Pr^L?

Comment: @AlexanderCampbell I thought this was written somewhere, but it is perhaps just gossip... (oops...)

Comment: This seems to fail badly when $C$ is stable. For example if $X=BG$ and $C=Vect$, the functor of coinvariants $Rep(G) \to Vect$ is usually not conservative. I guess you want to restrict to the case where $C$ is a topos or something?

Comment: As is probably clear, your argument also works for $\infty$-toposes and they also have that extra property @DylanWilson mentioned, that $\infty$-groupoid shaped colimite commute with contractible limits.

Comment: @SamGunningham can you say a bit more? By $Vect$ do you mean something like chain complexes on a field? Otherwise I'm not sure that's stable. And if you do mean something like that, can you say why you think it's the _stability_ that's getting in the way here, and not something else? I'd rather like my question to have an affirmative answer in the case of spectra.

Comment: @JonathanBeardsley Yes, sorry, by $Vect$ I meant chain complexes over a field $k$. The same example applies with spectra. I am not saying that stability in particular is a problem, just making the comment that one can't hope for comonadicity (or even conservativity) in such great generality.

Comment: For a concrete example, take $X=BC_2$ and $F$ the functor $BC_2\to Vect$ corresponding to the sign representation of $C_2$ (say over a field of characteristic not 2). Then the colimit of $F$ is just the coinvariants of the sign representation, which vanishes. Or more topologically, the corresponding local system on $BC_2$ has vanishing homology. So the functor is not conservative. One could just as well take the ambient category to be spectra, by embedding $Vect$ inside as $Hk$-modules.

Comment: @SamGunningham ah right. Well, this is an extremely unpleasant turn of events. =P

Comment: @SamGunningham am I confused in believing that the coinvariants of this are in fact $k$?

Comment: @JonathanBeardsley We are computing the derived coinvariants, i.e. the group homology $H_\ast(C_2,sgn)$ where $sgn$ denotes the 1-d non-trivial representation of $C_2$. Or equivalently the homology of $RP^\infty$ with coefficients in the corresponding local system. This is given by a chain complex with one cell in each degree $0,-1,-2,...$ (using cohomological conventions). The boundary maps are alternating between $0$ and $2$, but the last map (between degrees $-1$ and $0$) is a $2$ (compare with if we had taken trivial coefficients). This complex is acyclic.

Comment: More generally, the comonadicity you are asking for in the case of Vect is equivalent to saying that the natural functors between $C_\ast(\Omega X)$-modules and $C_\ast(X)$-comodules give an equivalence (say $X$ connected). As the above example shows, this doesn't have a hope when $X$ is not simply connected, but even if it is, I still think the comonadicity fails in general (if I understand correctly). E.g. is $X=S^3$, we have modules for a polynomial algebra vs comodules for an exterior algebra. Koszul duality fails to give an equivalence (without appropriately altering one of the sides).

Comment: I should say, I am also very interested in cases where this sort of comonadicity does in fact hold! (mostly in the case where $C$ is stable)

Comment: Maybe this is similar to what Sam is saying, but I don't think I believe the claim that $Top/X$ is comonadic over $Top$ via the colimit functor (although if $X$ is connected, it is certainly comonadic via the _forgetful_ functor) -- I doubt the colimit functor is conservative! I don't follow the argument, but it seems left-right symmetric, so it should also imply that $Top/X$ is monadic over $Top$ via the limit functor. For a counterexample to this claim, take $X = BC_2$. Then $(\emptyset \to C_2)^{hC_2}$ is an equivalence so the limit functor is not conservative and so not monadic.

Comment: @SamGunningham if you're interested in, I dunno, collaborating in some fashion on this type of thing, please send me an e-mail. Sounds like you have a lot more clarity about it than I do. :-)

Comment: @TimCampion The situation is not symmetric: $\mathrm{Fun}(X, Top)$ Is equivalent to $Top/X$ via the colimit functor and not via the limit functor.